# Не запускается gui если пишу что то для работы кнопок,лайн едита

Tags: python

Пытаюсь запустить проект с калькулятором, после запуска окно открывается на секунду и сразу вылетает.
Если же я не указываю параметры для кнопок, онли дизайн то все нормально запускается.
python 3.7.2

Comment: Понятно. Будем знать.

Comment: держите в курсе событий..